# creating an order in Magento using mule magento Connector

Tags: magento, mule

I don't see an operation to create an order in Magento connector of Mulesoft. Could someone tell me how can we create an order in magento using Magento connector of mulesoft.

Comment: The documentation on this extension is pretty much non existent. Link is 404 error, yet Mule keeps packaging this extension with every anypoint studio download

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `create-shopping-cart-order` operation to create an order from an existing cart:

```
<magento:create-shopping-cart-order quoteId="1" />
```

http://mulesoft.github.io/magento-connector/mule/magento-config.html#create-shopping-cart-order

Comment: Could you please direct me where I get the full details about quoteId, StoreId and Licenses. And when I try with create-shopping-cart-order and quoteId is "1", I am getting this error " faultString: Please check shipping address information. Please enter the first name. Please enter the last name. Please enter the street. Please enter the city. Please enter the telephone number. Please enter the zip/postal code. Please enter the country."

Comment: How would I provide Shipping address information and all other details to Magento connector.

Comment: Could you please share an example application of create-shopping-cart-order if available.